# li click event not working due to overlay (ie9 only)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

When user clicks on `a` tags `li` gets selected with ui-selected class which works fine in ff, chrome, ie8 and safari but not in ie9.

Please guide further.

[Note : Below is code sample for your handy reference]

```
` <div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="viewReorderList_Popup" style="display:block;">                    
<ul id="sortable0" >
<li class="ui-state-default" id="reorderLI_00" >             
<a style="float:left;" id="reorderList_00" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:addSelected();">
<img height="195" border="0" alt="" src="1.jpg">
</a>             
</li>
</ul>
</div>

<style>

#overlay
{
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
position: fixed;
width :100%;
height:100%;    
pointer-events: none;
opacity: 1;
}

#sortable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; opacity: 0.98; border: 5px dotted red;    }
</style>
<script>
function addSelected(){

$('#sortable0 li:first').addClass('ui-selected');
}
</script>`
```

Comment: Wow, your code is all messy! Where is the `ul` end tag? Why that `div` end tag at the top?

Comment: Get rid of `javascript:`, fix your bad HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably terminate your UL tag and see if that fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It works, just change your jquery selector from $('#sortable0 li:first') to $('#sortable li:first')

Comment: I posted it wrongly it is #sortable0 in <ul id="sortable0" >---</ul>

Comment: No problem, then change your css selector from `#sortable` to `#sortable0`